# Select Multiple Columns In Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to select multiple columns using the DatabaseHelper class, the following sql statement works on the database itself but not within android, only the first column is returned:

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM " + TABLE, null);
```

This only returns the first column but when executed in SQLite itself all columns are returned, am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: `This only returns the first column`... You are confusing columns and rows. You must **move** your cursor between rows, to get their values.

Comment: How do you iterate over the columns? Hi Der Golem, howdy mate?

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 3):

the single query will not return columns you also have to give the names of columns which you want to retrieve from the database

```
public ArrayList getDataFromDatabase() 
{
   ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "give your query here", null );
   res.moveToFirst();
   while(res.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
     //give the name of columns you want to retrieve from database one by one  
     array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(column 1)));
     array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(column 2)));
     res.moveToNext();
}
  return array_list;
}
```

Comment: I now select each column individually:

c = db.rawQuery("SELECT column1..
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT column2..
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT column3..

And later join the results. This assumes, and has been tested, that the database row of each column will match against each of the columns, so even if the row of a certain column is empty, a null value will be returned to keep the length of each columns equal. This will do for now.

Comment: Yes, as long as the columns are equal in rows (including null) then it works, I get the results of each column separately then join them later.

Comment: I only need to do this for a maximum of 3 columns, once the code is defined, I work directly from the DB and wont have to touch JAVA again.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
public ArrayList<ToDolistEntity> getAllTodolist(){
        ArrayList<ToDolistEntity> labels = new ArrayList<ToDolistEntity>();
        ToDolistEntity entity;
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DOLIST;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                entity=new ToDolistEntity();
                //labels.add(cursor.getString(1));

                entity.setCheckid(cursor.getInt(1));
                entity.set_toDolisttext(cursor.getString(2));           

                labels.add(entity);


            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer for this.

The approach of executing raw SQL statements is not really the desired approach. Sometimes when doing **very very** complex queries/joins etc. there may be a need to execute raw SQL, but I can't say that I have ever found myself in that situation.

The ideal approach would be using something like the following:

```
/**
 * Query the given table, returning a {@link Cursor} over the result set.
 *
 * @param table The table name to compile the query against.
 * @param columns A list of which columns to return. Passing null will
 *            return all columns, which is discouraged to prevent reading
 *            data from storage that isn't going to be used.
 * @param selection A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an
 *            SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null
 *            will return all rows for the given table.
 * @param selectionArgs You may include ?s in selection, which will be
 *         replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in order that they
 *         appear in the selection. The values will be bound as Strings.
 * @param groupBy A filter declaring how to group rows, formatted as an SQL
 *            GROUP BY clause (excluding the GROUP BY itself). Passing null
 *            will cause the rows to not be grouped.
 * @param having A filter declare which row groups to include in the cursor,
 *            if row grouping is being used, formatted as an SQL HAVING
 *            clause (excluding the HAVING itself). Passing null will cause
 *            all row groups to be included, and is required when row
 *            grouping is not being used.
 * @param orderBy How to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause
 *            (excluding the ORDER BY itself). Passing null will use the
 *            default sort order, which may be unordered.
 * @return A {@link Cursor} object, which is positioned before the first entry. Note that
 * {@link Cursor}s are not synchronized, see the documentation for more details.
 * @see Cursor
 */
public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having,
        String orderBy) {

    return query(false, table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy,
            having, orderBy, null /* limit */);
}
```

This method is on the ***SQLiteDatabase*** class, so can be executed on the ***db*** object from the question like so:

```
String[] columns = new String[]{"column1", "column2", "column3"};
Cursor cursor = db.query("TableName", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```